# polynomial with root and vector space

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

I am on the following problem from a maths book:

Be $E$ the vector space of polynomials in $x$ with complex coefficients of degree strictly less than $n, n > 2$ and $x_1$, $x_2$ two distinct elements in $\mathbb{C}$.

a) Show that the following subsets of E are sub vector spaces of E: the set $F_1$ of polynomials with the root $x_1$, the set $F_2$ of polynomials with the root $x_2$, the set F of polynomials with roots $x_1$ and $x_2$. Find their dimensions.

b) Show that E is the direct sum of $F_1$ + $F_2$

I could solve easily part a) and find that the dimensions of $F_1$ and $F_2$ are $n - 1$ and dimension of $F$ is $n - 2$.

However, I am stuck on part b) that seems to be illogical since $\dim(E)$ is $n$ or do I have misunderstood something?

Thanks for your support

Comment: The sum cannot be direct, since the intersection of $F_1$ and $F_2$ is not trivial. Are you sure they don't want you to show $F=F_1+ F_2$ ?

Comment: Actually, it is to show that E = $F_1$ + $F_2$, not that E is direct sum. I misinterpreted the question of the book

Answer (score 1):

$F_1$ (or $F_2$) is a proper(!) subspace of $F_1+F_2$, hence $\dim(F_1+F_2)>\dim F_1=n-1$. This shows that $F_1+F_2=E$. However, contrary to what you wrote, $E$ is in general not the *direct* sum of $F_1$ and $F_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. The proof is clear. however, I am still a bit confused on the interpretation of the result. If we had $x_1$, $x_2$,...,$x-n$ distinct roots, then we would have E = $F_1$ + ...+ $F_n$ = $F_1$ + $F_2$ ? It's difficult for me to understand the result